# How to see real destination IP using tcpdump?

Tags: tcpdump

I'm a newbie with tcpdump.
My setup is simple:

- 1 machine A behind a router B
- 1 machine C outside, on the Internet

On machine A, I ping machine C, and I want to track what's happening with tcpdump:

- `tcpdump` on machine A shows an ICMP packet from IP (A) to IP (C)
- Then `tcpdump` on machine C shows an ICMP packet from IP (B) to IP (C)
- Then `tcpdump` on machine C sends an echo reply from IP (C) to IP (B)
- Then `tcpdump` on machine A shows an echo reply from IP (C) to IP (A)

So, at some point in router B (I cannot run `tcpdump` on the router), the IPs are converted from IP (B) and IP (A). I assume that the "real destination IP" = IP (A) should be stored somewhere deep within the ICMP packet, so that the router can redirect it correctly. But I can't find any option of tcpdump to show this "real destination IP" when it's run on machine C? What is this option, or how can I see it?

Comment: "I assume that the "real destination IP" = IP (A) should be stored somewhere deep within the ICMP packet, so that the router can redirect it correctly." Incorrect assumption, you need to learn about [Network Address Translation (NAT)](http://www.firewall.cx/networking-topics/network-address-translation-nat/227-nat-concepts.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link !
It gives interesting insight for my question. There is one big difference though: the first answer in this link assumes that ports are used to transfer the packet, but in my question, I'm asking about ICMP paquets, which, as far as I know, are not associated to ports. But I guess there is another kind of "identifier" that is used for ICMP paquets instead of ports; I'll look for that. Thanks again !